# how to get dock postion and direction?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'll show a browserwindow where the mouse clicks, but to avoid the taskbar/dock location, how do I get the dock orientation left, right, or down?

```
const primaryDisplay = screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
const { workArea, id: primaryId, bounds: primaryBounds } = primaryDisplay;
```

I can determine whether the dock is on the side or below and the height of the dock by the difference between the width and height of the workArea and bounds, but I can't tell whether it is on the left or right. Please help me